# Calling a GET on the Apigee HTTPTargetConnection when the request was POST

Tags: apigee

I need to call a legacy API which uses GET.
My API proxy uses POST.

I tried using in `AssignMessage`:
`<AssignTo type="request" createNew="false"/>`

and

`<Set> ...  <Verb>GET</Verb>`

But it still does a POST on the target API.

What is the proper way of converting?
Will the gateway automatically convert the POST form parameters into GET query parameters?
Is `message.queryparam` the same for both GET and POST?

Comment: As an API design i suggest you do not convert a GET to POST just like that, unless you are doing more orchestration in your proxy which is in line with POST semantics. My suggestion is to honour the semantics of POST and GET rather than use the tool for conversion because the tool is capable of doing so. You can ignore the suggestion if you have already thought through this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes I'm aware of this. The original API uses GET for an action that makes a change, so it's better as a POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When converting the Verb from `POST` to `GET`, the policy will NOT automatically convert the form parameters to query parameters.  You will need to use the `<Add>` and/or `<Remove>` functionality of the `AssignMessage` policy to manipulate the message further.  Example use in the `AssignMessage` policy to add the queryparams, referencing the formparams:

```
<Add>
    <QueryParams>
        <QueryParam name="q1">{request.formparam.q1}</QueryParam>
    </QueryParams>
</Add>
```

Also, in your question you mentioned that the API Proxy accepts the request using method as `POST`.  Then, you have a policy to set `GET`:

> `<Set> ... <Verb>GET</Verb>`
>
> But it still does a GET on the target API.

What's the problem?  Isn't that what you are expecting?  The request goes into the Apigee API Proxy as `POST`, the proxy converts the method (verb) to `GET`, and sends the request to the backend legacy API using `GET`.

Note: `<AssignTo>` is optional in the AssignMessage.  Try leaving this out if the method is not being set properly.  In its absence, the message at the current point in the flow will be modified.

Comment: My mistake in the question. Should be "it still does a POST on the target API." Let me try this.

Answer (score 2):

Change this predefined variable to post

```
request.verb = "GET"
```

Note:  If you do this and you have a flow condition based on request.verb="POST" that will not work well in the response. So you need to use another variable to use in the flow condition.

Here is the policy code that worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="changeverbassignmessage">
    <DisplayName>ChangeVerbAssignMessage</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <AssignVariable>
        <Name>request.verb</Name>
      <Value>GET</Value>
        <Ref/>
    </AssignVariable>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

Comment: Where is the correct place to put this? I only know about the AssignMessage policy. I tried:

<AssignVariable>
    <Name>request.verb</Name>
    <Value>GET</Value>
</AssignVariable>


But it had no effect. A POST was still sent to the target.

Comment: Sounds correct. You have to make sure you add the policy in the request path, that is before hitting the target. Have edited the answer to add a sample policy that worked for me.  To be sure that your target is receiving the GET verb, please debug trace and select the target and watch the request details.

Comment: +1 for providing the javascript equivalent in the answer, thanks! `context.setVariable('target.verb', 'GET');`