# POST call converting to GET

Tags: apigee

I am new to apigee.

I am trying to make a post call in apigee with queryparameters.

The flow is below.

```
Client send request --> verify API key ---> extract payload --> remove access token --> call target endpoint conditional based on POST
```

I am using curl command to make POST call.But issue is while calling target endpoint its taking as /GET call and condition is evaluating to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apigee can convert in inbound POST to a back-end GET. In Apigee that means using a policy to rebuild the call, to use a GET method (verb) on your target back-end, when you need to receive a POST from your upstream calling client. You will need to use the AssignMessage policy. These product docs are exactly what you need to review:
https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/assign-message-policy#set-verb

Example, AssignMessage:

```
<AssignTo type="request" createNew="false"/>
```

and

```
<Set> ...  <Verb>GET</Verb>
```

Note though that when converting the method (verb) from POST to GET, the policy will **not** automatically convert the POST's form parameters to query parameters. You will need to use the `<Add>` and/or `<Remove>` functionality of the AssignMessage policy to manipulate the message further. Example use in the AssignMessage policy to add the queryparams, referencing the formparams:

```
<Add>
    <QueryParams>
        <QueryParam name="q1">{request.formparam.q1}</QueryParam>
    </QueryParams>
</Add>
```

*Credit to user [Michael Russo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3195620/michael-russo) for his [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21264371/6745230) about this from eight years ago.*

Comment: @evanshe Thanks.This was the issue